# Photo covering job description

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Here is screenshot of my careers profile. My photo is hiding my current job title.

Comment: This bug report doesn't make much sense without a screenshot. Wouldn't it be a good idea to keep it there?

Comment: Also, the image is still viewable from [the edit history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/120306/revisions).

Comment: its screenshot of my old resume. I have to download it, edit it, and upload it again. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a minor bug in the edit view, since we make space for those “edit” links on the right-hand side. Only *you* see the edit view – try the “employer” or “public” views and let me know if any problems.

Comment: public view is just fine.

Comment: Why dont you remove the photo from the edit view at all. I hope its not required there.

Comment: @hrishikeshp19 We include the photo in the edit view because you have the option of hiding it.